# How can I cut the string into pieces and then stored them in array

Tags: vb.net, arrays

In my website I have a textbox that allow user to enter a group of numbers like this:

```
(118,38,137,15,156,14,157,36,152,49,142,57)
```

How can I store these numbers in an array like the following?:

```
[118    38    137   15    156    14    157    36    152    49    142    57]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method:

```
yourString = yourString.Substring(1, yourString.Length - 2) ' Trim parentheses.
Dim result As String() = yourString.Split(","c)
```

The `Split` method has several overloads, depending on purpose. I’ve chosen the simplest here, that only takes a single `Character` argument, in this case `","c`, a comma.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
Dim str As string = "(118,38,137,15,156,14,157,36,152,49,142,57)"
Dim matches As MatchCollection = New Regex(@"\d+").Matches(str)
Dim ints As Integer() = New Integer(matches.Count - 1) }
Dim i as Integer
For i = 0 To ints.Length - 1
    ints[i] = int.Parse(If(matches.Item(i).Value <> Nothing, _
                           a.Item(i).Value, "").ToString())
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

See [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

```
myArray = "118,38,137,15,156,14,157,36,152,49,142,57".Split (",")
```